# SurfaceView doesn't work with Video 360 used Panframe library

Tags: android, video

I have two videos, first video with suferfaceView, I use MediaPlayer Library, and another video is 360 video, I use Panframe Library. My problem is that I can't show these videos the same time. When I load 360 video and after I add surface. In screen app show only video 360.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
public void loadVideo(String filename)
{

    mPfview = PFObjectFactory.view(MainActivity.this);
    mPfasset = PFObjectFactory.assetFromUri(this, Uri.parse(filename), this);

    mPfview.displayAsset(mPfasset);
    mPfview.setNavigationMode(mCurrentNavigationMode);

    //mViewSurfaceLibrary
    mFrameContainer.addView(mPfview.getView(), 0);

    mVidSurface = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surfView);
    mVidHolder = mVidSurface.getHolder();
    mVidHolder.addCallback(this);

}
```

Does someone know how to use Panframe Library and add an overlay surfaceView?

Both videos seem to be playing as I can hear the sound of the one playing in the surfaceview, but the Panframe Library is overlaying everything.

Comment: when u want to replace  360  to surface view at a time first u release the 360 view and then you add the surface view. mFrameContainer.removeView(mPfview .getView());
     mPfasset .stop(); 
     mPfview .release();
     mPfasset .release();     now u reset the view . i hope it is useful to you . thanks. @Cabezas